# Noisy kinect color (rgb) images

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni

i'm using opencv interface (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html?highlight=kinect) to get color (rgb) and depth frames from a kinect camera. For a standard VGA 640x480 resolution and with code like

```
capture.retrieve( bgrImage, OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE );
```

i get this :

[image]

I think this is really noisy. Is this normal quality for a kinect rgb camera?
I tried various filtering (blurring, sharpening, opening..) procedures but i got minor improvements.

Comment: What is the light like in your room?  That looks to me to be pretty typical of a low light image.  Try adding a few flood lights.  Have you tried other cameras in the same space?

Comment: Do you want to know whether this is the expected image for kinect or are you interested in knowing which filters can be applied in this situation ?

Comment: @Evil Closet Monkey: light was surely insufficient, but i also wanted to know which filters could be applied (@mmgp). Thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions under which this image was taken are unknown to me, and I cannot attest the quality of the images taken using Kinect, so I'm ignoring this part of the question.

A very simple thing you can do to likely improve the image quality is to average several frames you might be getting. That is it.

Another options include, for example, Bilateral Filtering or Mean Shift Filtering (and I'm not sure how you would do the later purely with ready OpenCV functions) that can handle well this kind of noise. For instance, here are three rows of images. In the second column you see the edges found by Canny for the image in the first column. The first row shows the input image as is, the second row is the result of a particular Mean Shift, and the last one is for Bilateral Filtering.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

While the results are particularly good, the problem is that these filtering techniques are slow for the typical computers used nowadays.